# how to link boost with Xcode

Tags: c++, xcode, boost, macports, osx-elcapitan

I've upgraded my OS to El Capitan. I've used Macports to install Boost. All tutorials I've seen use this folder `/usr/local/include` to include the header files. In my case, I can't see this folder listed in my system unless this folder is hidden.  I have no idea where the libraries installed via macports. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Macports usually installs in /opt/local. Click on the project (1) and Build Settings (2) and point to headers with /opt/local/include (3).

[image]

And if you need to link to a library add /opt/local/lib and add required libraries via Build Phases.

[image]

Comment: for me the path is `/usr/local/`

Comment: Aah, have used homebrew for some years now. Have macport changed default-installation-folder?

Comment: Yes, homebrew defaults to /usr/local. The questioner asked about macports which defaults to /opt/local.